# Where to store and cache JSON?

Tags: json, heroku

Have been considering caching my JSON on Amazon Cloudfront.

The issue with that is it can take 15 minutes to manually clear that cache when the JSON is updated.

Is there a way to store a simple JSON value in a CDN-like http cache that -

- does not touch an application server (heroku) after intial generation
- allows me to instantly expire a cache

**Update**

In response to AdamKG's point:

> If it's being "updated", it's not static :D Write a new version and
>   tell your servers to use the new URL.

My actual idea is to cache a new CloudFront url every time a html page changes. That was my original focus.

The reason I want to JSON is to store the version number for that latest CloudFront url. That way I can make an AJAX call to discover what version to load, then a second AJAX call to actually load the content. This way I never need to expire CloudFront content, I just redirect the ajax loading it.

But then I have the issue of the JSON needing to be cached. I don't want people hitting the Heroku dynamos every time they want to see the single JSON version number. I know memcache and rack can help me speed that up, but it's a problem I just dont want to have.

Some ideas I've had:

- Maybe there is a third party service, similar to a Memcache db, that allows me to be expose a value in a JSON url?  That way my dynamos are never touched.
- Maybe there is an alternative to Cloudfront that allows for quicker manual expiration? I know that kinda defeats the nature of caching, but maybe there more intermediary services, like a varnish layer or something.

Comment: "does not touch an application server" isn't clear - as in, the JSON data doesn't go through the application server, or the application server can't know that the JSON is being changed, period? Because the simple/correct/best way is to write a *new* resource every time it's changed, and update the application to point to that new resource.

Comment: I mean the cache is purely a static file cache.  Could store the JSON in memcache, for example, but would want to avoid hitting the Heroku servers to retrieve the value. So hoping for something more simple and static CDN-like.

Comment: If it's being "updated", it's not static :D Write a new version and tell your servers to use the new URL.

Comment: It's interesting you say that because that's the exact issue I'm trying to solve.  I'll update the question to respond to this.

Comment: Is this something that has *really* become a problem - are your dynos really unable to handle the load? If waiting 15 minutes is unacceptable, what would be a more acceptable delay between updates? Could it be 1 minute or 15 seconds? Or does it *have* to be instant?

Answer (score 4):

One method is to use asset expiration similar to the way that Rails static assets are expired. Rails adds a hash signature to filenames, so something like `application.js` becomes `application-abcdef1234567890.js`. Then, each time a user requests your page, if application.js has been updated, the script tag has the new address.

Here is how I envision you doing this:

```
User → CloudFront (CDN) → Your App (Origin)
```

User requests `http://www.example.com/`. The page has meta tag

```
<meta content="1231231230" name="data-timestamp" />
```

based on the last time you updated the JSON resource. This could be generated from something like `<%= Widget.order(updated_at: :desc).pluck(:updated_at).first.to_i %>` if you are using Rails.

Then, in your application's JavaScript, grab the timestamp and use it for your JSON url.

```
var timestamp = $('meta[name=data-timestamp]').attr('content');
$.get('http://cdn.example.com/data-' + timestamp + '.json', function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  blah(data);
});
```

The first request to CloudFront will hit your origin server at `/data/data-1231231230.json`, which can be generated and cached forever. Each time your JSON should be updated, the user gets a new URL to query the CDN.

### Update

Since you mention that the actual page is what you want to cache heavily, you are left with a couple options. If you really want CloudFront in front of your server, your only real option would be to send an invalidation request every time your homepage updates. You can invalidate 1,000 times per month for free, and $5 per 1,000 after that. In addition, CloudFront invalidations are not fast, and you will still have a delay before the page is updated.

The other option is to cache your content in Memcached and serve it from your dynos. I will assume that you are using Ruby on Rails or another Ruby framework based on your asking history (but please clarify if you are not). This entails getting [Rack::Cache](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-rails31) installed. The instructions on Heroku are for caching assets, but this will work for dynamic content, as well. Next, you would use Rack::Cache's [`invalidate`](http://rtomayko.github.io/rack-cache/api/classes/Rack/Cache/MetaStore.html#M000074) method each time the page is updated. Yes, your dyno's will handle some of the load, but it will be a simple Memcached lookup and response.

Your server layout would look like:

User → CloudFront (CDN) → Rack::Cache → Your App (Origin) on cdn.example.com
User → Rack::Cache → Your App (Origin) on www.example.com

When you serve static assets like your images, CSS, and JavaScript, use the cdn.example.com domain. This will route requests through CloudFront and they will be cached for long periods of time. Requests to your app will go directly to your Heroku dyno, and the cacheable parts will be stored and retrieved by Rack::Cache.

Comment: Thanks and I like your idea. Unfortunately the actual page is the thing I want to cache heavily, so updating meta tags would mean updating the page. Have written more in my question :)